# Function One to One with coordinates

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

$f: \Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R^2$, $g(a,b) = (b + 2, 5a - 8)$

I was able to determine if this function was onto or not but am having trouble determining if it is one to one. I used the understanding that if $(a,b)$ is an element of $g$ and $(c,b)$ is an element of $g$, show $a = c$.

I ended up with

$g(a,b) = (b + 2, 5a - 8)$ and $g(c,b) = (b + 2, 5c - 8)$

I am not sure what to do after this to check if $a = c$ or not.
Any help would be appreciated! Thank you

Comment: From $g(a,b) = g(c,d)$ prove that $a = c$ and $b = d$. Note that the variables involved are $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $g(a,b)=g(c,d)$, then we have

$$(b+2, 5a-8)=(d+2, 5c-8)$$

Now compare the component, are you able to conclude that $(a,b)=(c,d)$?

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple misunderstandings that I need to address before I can answer your question. As you highlight in your answer, a function $g$ is formally a very special subset of $\Bbb R^2 \times \Bbb R^2$--$g \subseteq \Bbb R^2 \times \Bbb R^2$. If $(x,y) \in g$, then we write $g(x) = y$. By definition of function, for every $x \in \Bbb R^2$, there is one and only one $y$ such that $(x,y) \in g$, so this notation is not ambiguous.

In this case however, $\Bbb R^2$ is a collection of ordered pairs of real numbers. So our "$x$" and "$y$" above are actually pairs of numbers $((a,b),(c,d)) \in g$. For notational convenience we write $g((a,b)) = g(a,b)$ to cut down on parentheses.

So to check $g$ is onto, we need to check if $(a,b) \in \Bbb R^2$ and $(c,d) \in \Bbb R^2$ such that $g(a,b) = g(c,d)$, then $(a,b) = (c,d)$. Note that we don't just need to check that $g(a,b) = g(c,b) \implies a = c$, since the elements of our domain our ordered pairs.

---

To actually get to your question, say $g(a,b) = g(c,d)$. Then

$$
(b+2, 5a-8) = (d+2, 5c-8).
$$

So $b+2 = d+2 \implies b= d$ and $5a-8 = 5c - 8 \implies a = c$. Thus $(a,b) = (c,d)$ and we're done.

Comment: Thank you for clearing my misunderstandings!
I also wanted to clarify that isn't this checking to see if the function is one to one and not onto? You mentioned onto in your explanation so I am not sure if that was by mistake or not.